# Address Sanitizer - can I stop after N defects?

Tags: address-sanitizer

I realize that some Address Sanitizer capabilities may vary from GCC to clang ; my interest here is primarily with GCC (currently using GCC 6.2 and 7.3)

I can use `ASAN_OPTIONS` to set `halt_on_error=0` to keep going after a defect is reported, or set it to 1 to stop as soon as the first defect is reported.

What I am looking for, is a way to stop after N defects. `halt_on_error=N` doesn't work, because it's simply a binary setting (on/off).

Is there any other way to achieve this:

- When simply running the exe at the command line, via some env setting ?
- When inside the debugger - e.g. something like `b some_asan_defect_reporting_function if (asan_defect_count == N)`

Thanks in advance for any info on the above.

Gordon

Comment: BTW, I realize that I could implement this myself by adding an implementation of __asan_on_error() that counts the number of times it has been called etc. ; before doing this though, I just wanted to check whether the functionality is already implemented somewhere in the sanitizer.

Comment: `halt_on_error=N` - I was under impression that `N` here means number of _unique_ errors.

Comment: Unfortunatley not:setenv ASAN_OPTIONS "halt_on_error=2" ; a.out
ERROR: Invalid value for bool option: '2'
ERROR: Flag parsing failed.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a supplementary `ASAN_OPTIONS=max_errors=N` flag for `halt_on_error` but it raised too many questions during code review and didn't have compelling use-cases so I abandoned it half-way (you can see it was dropped at [this stage](https://reviews.llvm.org/D12318?vs=33570&id=38931&whitespace=ignore-most#toc)). If you feel it might be useful, try filing a bug in [Sanitizers tracker](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues).